# jQuery Mobile Without all the Styling

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I've built a mobile web app, styling and all, but I recently decided there were a few parts of jQuery mobile that I wanted to use (The ajax page navigation and history being the main ones).

I've searched around for an equivalent, but so far no luck. So I bit the bullet and went with jQuery mobile, but it applies all its default styling to everything.

It seems everything has a separate font-family declaration or text-shadow or color style added to it. Overriding all of it just seems like overkill.

Is there a way to use jQuery Mobile without all the aesthetic styling? Or a good plugin that duplicates the page functionality?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery Mobile 1.1, you can add `data-enhance="false"` to any container, and jQuery Mobile will leave those elements alone style-wise. Then you can define your own custom styles.

Source: [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html)

Comment: Wow, thanks. Not sure how I missed that. Doesn't completely eliminate all the styles, but it's pretty close.